# About the follow button

Tags: support, notifications, follow-post

One can push the "follow" button below a question in order to get advised of new developments. 
Can it happen that one gets news from the "recent inbox message" about some questions that one has browsed often but for which one has not pushed that button?

Comment: You get notification on your posts. IIRC you get notifications for questions where you have offered a bounty. Also you get comment replies if somebody uses `@username` or if you are the only user who commented: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: Did you mean notifications from questions you haven't interacted in any way? (I.e., none of the possibilities mentioned in the previous comment applies and you haven't followed the post.)

Comment: @Martin, yes, that's right.I hadn't interacted in any way.

Comment: Possibly some additional data might be useful here. (At least mentioning which question it was and whether the inbox notification was about a comment or an answer or something else. Maybe also some screenshots.) Even that, I have some doubts whether regular users would be able to help. Maybe people from the Stack Exchange team have some option to log as some specific user when investigating something.

Comment: Also, if you are quite confident that you haven't interacted with that post, maybe this could be tagged ([meta-tag:bug]) (instead of or in addition to ([meta-tag:support])).